# How to access a specific variable in a custom class after it's JSON data has been updated in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a custom class I created, it's data will change after the JSON is updated.

```
 class NetflixMovieData: NSObject {
    let name: String
    let year: String
    let poster : String
    }
init(name: String?, year: String?,poster: String?) {
        self.name = name ?? ""
        self.year = year ?? ""
        self.poster = poster ?? ""
    }
}
```

After I get the info from JSON.  I save it in a local array.

```
var movieInfo : [NetflixMovieData] = []

func parseJSON () {

//Getting JSON Data code

     let netflixMovieInfo = NetflixMovieData(name: name, year: year, poster: poster)
            print(self.movieInfo)
            movieInfo.append(netflixMovieInfo)
}
```

This is where the issue starts, I know the info is there because I print it out to the console first.  I want to change a local variable in the view controller by this code:

```
 var posterImage : UIImage?

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
//boilerpate code

self.posterImage = UIImage(named: self.movieInfo.poster)
}
```

but it keeps giving me an error "Value of type [NetflixMovieData]has no member poster".  I'm trying to access the "poster" variable in the "NetflixMovieData" after it has been updated with the JSON data.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: first of all, a `let` variable cannot be changed, its like a `final`, or `readonly`. You can't update its value. Second, your `init` method looks like its outside your class declaration. and third, why are you inheriting from `NSObject`, that happens automatically. Please correct me if any of these statements are false

Comment: Those statements are correct, thats why I save the class to a local array and then use that array to gather the info.  Whenever a new search is used the array is cleared out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your movieInfo is an array.

```
self.posterImage = UIImage(named: self.movieInfo[0].poster)
```

also check if there is any element in self.movieInfo before this

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that the way to access it but for some strange reason the image isn't showing up. If I use print(self.movieInfo[0].poster) the URL shows up. Ex. (http://netflixroulette.net/api/posters/60032563.jpg)  but the image says nil.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user5005376 uiimage imagenamed is used to init image in your image assets. to init imageview with web url search how to use sdwebimage